# Why does '/' match correctly to a Rack application in my Rails 3 app, but no other route does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm using Rails 3.0.6.

In my lib directory I have a example_app.rb, which is simply a Sinatra app:

```
class ExampleApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "Hello from Sinatra"
  end
end
```

And I'm autoloading it with the application.rb config.auto_load_paths configuration.

In my routes file, I have only:

```
match "/" => ExampleApp
```

And that matches fine when I run the rails server (Webrick). However if I try:

```
match "/example" => ExampleApp
```

Visiting localhost:3000/example gives me a 'No route matches "/example"' error. Running rake routes shows the route though:

```
example  /example(.:format) {:to=>ExampleApp}
```

If I try and match '/example' against a controller action it works fine, but not to that Sinatra app up above, so I'm not sure what's going on. I know there's something small I'm missing that I'm not finding in the routing documentation on the Rails site.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your Sinatra app only responds to requests made to `/`. You need to either add

```
get '/example'
```

or do a wildcard match using `*`

```
get '*' do
  "Hello from Sinatra"
end
```

Comment: I still get "No route matches" error if I change my Sinatra route to a matching '/example'. Additionally, this seems to conflict with a blog post I read at http://yehudakatz.com/2009/12/26/the-rails-3-router-rack-it-up/ which '/home' used as an example in the Rails 3 route should match fine to a Sinatra app with simply a '/' route.

Comment: I just created a new app and tried this. Yehuda's examples seems to be not working (may be a mistake on his end), but when i do `match '/example', :to => MyApp`, and a `get '/example'` in `MyApp`, I get a valid response. Could you make sure you're doing it correctly? I tested using Rails 3.0.6, and Sinatra 1.2.2.

Comment: Ok I got it to work using your example now after I created another application. May've been as simple as I needed to restart Webrick with my original example, my bad. Thank you!